# Adding nested dictionaries into an already existing JSON file with dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I've recently started to learn some python.
After finishing all the learnpython.org tutorials I'm trying something on my own (So you know my knowledge level).

I want to build a small script that lets you build a DnD character and save it in a file. The idea was to use JSON (Since this was included in the learnpython tutorials) and put in dictionaries along the lines of:

`data = { playerName ; {"Character Name" : characterName, "Character Class" : characterClass...ect.}}`

I was hoping that it is possible to add new dics into the JSON file inside that original data dic, So the dictionary is a list of playerName's that have the character dics under them.

Not only did I fail to get it exactly like this, I also fail at just adding following dictionaries without making the file unreadable. Here is my code, since it isn't very long:

```
import json


def dataCollection():
    print("Please write your character name:")
    characterName = input()
    print("%s, a good name! \nNow tell me your race:" % characterName)
    characterRace = input()
    print("And what about the class?")
    characterClass = input()
    print("Ok so we have; \nName = %s \nRace = %s \nClass = %s \nPlease tell me the player name now:" % (characterName, characterRace, characterClass))
    playerName = input()
    print("Nice to meet you %s. \nI will now save your choices..." % playerName)
    localData = { playerName : 
                 {"Character Name" : characterName,
                  "Character Class" : characterClass,
                  "Character Race" : characterRace}}

    with open("%s_data_file.json" % playerName, "a") as write_file:
        json.dump(localData, write_file)
        
    


dataCollection()

with open("data_file.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
# different .json name here since I'm trying around with different files

print(data)
```

Edit: It might also be possible that JSON is not the "right" thing to use for my idea. If you have any alternative ideas for storing that information (Besides straight txt file), feel free to suggest them!

Answer (score 0):

i made little modification, i try to read the file for init the data json, if it fail i init the data.

```
import json


def createPlayer():
    print("Please write your character name : ")
    characterName = input()
    print("%s, a good name! \nNow tell me your race : " % characterName)
    characterRace = input()
    print("Nice to meet you %s. \nI will now save your choices..." % characterName)

    try :
        with open('data_file.json') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
    except :
        data = {}
        data['player'] = []

    data['player'].append({
    'name': characterName,
    'race': characterRace,
    })

    with open("data_file.json", "w+") as write_file:
        json.dump(data, write_file)

createPlayer()

with open("data_file.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)

print(data)
```

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Azubi-el\source\repos\stuff.py", line 26, in <module>
    createPlayer()
  File "C:\Users\Azubi-el\source\repos\stuff.py", line 18, in createPlayer
    data['player'].append({
KeyError: 'player' ```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way you think of a dictionnary might not be exactly what it is.
A dictionary is a data structure that can holds many key-value pairs.

Here the key to your dictionary would be the player's name and the value would be the dictionary that holds the character's name, class and race.

So a json file that holds a dictionary cannot be appended to because a json file can only hold 1 json object.

```
{ 'playerName': {...character\'s attributes...}}
```

If you were to open the file and append a json object (like you do at the end of `dataCollection`) then your file would be like this

```
{ 'playerName':
    {...characters attributes...}
}
{ 'playerName2':
    {...characters attributes...}
}
```

And when reading the file `json` will stop when the first json object it finds will end. So it won't load the 2nd dictionary.

If you want to add something to the dictionary inside your json file, you need to load the json file to access the dictionary and then add your new key-value pair and then dump this new dictionary. Which will result in the following json file:

```
{ 'playerName':
    {...characters attributes...},
  'playerName2':
    {...characters attributes...}
}
```

I hope it's kinda clear.

Comment: This helped a lot. Working on new version, I will edit this comment or make a new one if I got it working!